# Dom parser "cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Tags: java, mysql, dom, xml-parsing

I have an xml file.I need to read data and insert it into mysql database. I have an exam table and eno is primary key for this table and foreign key in question table.Although question table is empty it throws an exception.

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`a3_2`.`answeroption`, CONSTRAINT `answeroption_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`eno`, `qno`) REFERENCES `question` (`eno`, `qno`))
```

So, What is the wrong thing in this code?

here my xml file:

```
<Assignment3>
  <exam>
    <eno>3</eno>
    <etitle>Elementary History</etitle>
    <timeAllowed>10</timeAllowed>
    <numberOfQuestionsPerPage>3</numberOfQuestionsPerPage>
  </exam>
  <question>
    <eno>3</eno>
    <qno>1</qno>
    <qtext>The Battle of Gettysburg was fought during which war?</qtext>
    <correctAnswer>C</correctAnswer>
    <eno>3</eno>
    <qno>2</qno>
    <qtext>Neil Armstrong and Buzz Aldrin walked how many 
minutes on the moon in 1696?</qtext>
    <correctAnswer>B</correctAnswer>
    <eno>3</eno>
    <qno>3</qno>
    <qtext>Which Presidents held office during World War II?</qtext>
    <correctAnswer>D</correctAnswer>
    <eno>3</eno>
    <qno>4</qno>
    <qtext>In a communist economic system, people:</qtext>
    <correctAnswer>B</correctAnswer>
    <eno>3</eno>
    <qno>5</qno>
    <qtext>Which president did not die while in office?</qtext>
    <correctAnswer>D</correctAnswer>
    <eno>3</eno>
    <qno>6</qno>
    <qtext>Which state refused to attend the Constitutional Convention 
in 1787 because it didn't want the United States government 
to interfere with already established state affairs?</qtext>
    <correctAnswer>A</correctAnswer>
    <eno>3</eno>
    <qno>7</qno>
    <qtext>Who founded Buddhism?</qtext>
    <correctAnswer>A</correctAnswer>
    <eno>3</eno>
    <qno>8</qno>
    <qtext>Where is India?</qtext>
    <correctAnswer>D</correctAnswer>
    <eno>3</eno>
    <qno>9</qno>
    <qtext>What is the dominant religion in India?</qtext>
    <correctAnswer>B</correctAnswer>
    <eno>3</eno>
    <qno>10</qno>
    <qtext>Near which river did archaeologists find India's 
first civilization?</qtext>
    <correctAnswer>B</correctAnswer>
  </question>
</Assignment3>
```

here is my source code:

```
    Node listOfQuestions = doc.getElementsByTagName("question").item(0);
    NodeList qItem =listOfQuestions.getChildNodes();


//FOR QUESTION TABLE
        for(int s=0; s<qItem.getLength(); s++)
        {
            int eno=0;
            int qno=0;
            String qtext=null;
            String correctAnswer=null;
            Node item=qItem.item(s);
            NodeList itemChildren =item.getChildNodes();
            for(int i=0;i<itemChildren.getLength();i++)
            {
                Node itemChild =itemChildren.item(i);
                if("eno".equals(itemChild.getNodeName())) {
                    eno=Integer.parseInt(itemChild.getNodeValue());
                    System.out.println(eno);
                }
                if("qno".equals(itemChild.getNodeName())) {
                   qno=Integer.parseInt(itemChild.getNodeValue());
                   System.out.println(qno);
                }
                if("qtext".equals(itemChild.getNodeName())) {
                    qtext=itemChild.getTextContent();
                    System.out.println(qtext);
                }
                if("correctAnswer".equals(itemChild.getNodeName())) {
                     correctAnswer=itemChild.getTextContent().trim();
                     System.out.println(correctAnswer);
                }
            }
                int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into a3_2.question(eno,qno,qtext,correctAnswer) values('"+eno+"','"+qno+"','"+qtext+"','"+correctAnswer+"')");

            }
```

Comment: Is this [homework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/211183)?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes it is.I need help

Comment: This doesn't really look like an xml/dom problem, since the error is coming from MySQL. It appears to be happening when you insert into answeroption, but I don't see that in the code.